# send image in e-mail content Drupal 7 webform

Tags: webforms, drupal-7

I'm trying to customize the confirmation email template that sends the Drupal webform by following

```
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') .t('----,') .($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p> <b>' : '') .t('Michel Kevorkian') .($email['html'] ? '</b></p>' : ''); ?>    
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') .t('23 rue du Départ') .($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') .t('75014 Paris') .($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') .t('T: + 33 6 64 30 24 03') .($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') .t('T: + 374 55 94 75') .($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') .t('www.asifabtp.fr') .($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>
```

I need to add the company logo as part of signature like this

```
LOGO GOES HERE   
23 rue du Départ
75014 Paris
T: + 33 6 64 30 24 03
T: + 374 55 94 75
www.asifabtp.fr
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://cheekymonkeymedia.ca/blog/drupal-planet/4-easy-steps-configure-drupal-send-html-emails
This tutorial shows how it is done

For this you need 2 modules

https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem
https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail